# ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' when trying to run PyQT4 script in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt4, python-3.6

When i trying to run the below code, this code is in a script named as **plot.py**

```
import sys
# Python Qt4 bindings for GUI objects
from PyQt4 import QtGui
# Numpy functions for image creation
import numpy as np
# Matplotlib Figure object
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
# import the Qt4Agg FigureCanvas object, that binds Figure to
# Qt4Agg backend. It also inherits from QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class Qt4MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Class to represent the FigureCanvas widget"""
    def __init__(self):
        # Standard Matplotlib code to generate the plot
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.x = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        self.y = np.cos(2*np.pi*self.x)
        self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y)
        # initialize the canvas where the Figure renders into
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

# Create the GUI application
qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create the Matplotlib widget
mpl = Qt4MplCanvas()
# show the widget
mpl.show()
# start the Qt main loop execution, exiting from this script
# with the same return code of Qt application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

I get this the complete error details,

```
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pqt4gui/plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import decorators as dec
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\decorators.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import SkipTest, assert_warns
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
```

I am new to programing and i did some research regarding this error and non was fruitful.

Comment: I do not have that error, you can tell me that you get to just run the following line with nothing else: `import numpy as np`

Comment: Do you have a file called `random.py` in your working directory?

Comment: @ellanesc No still i cannot run. But i have installed numpy for python 3.6. Numpy works with other scripts.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes i do have a file called random.py

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Your comment made me to delete the file random.py and it worked!! May i know why that file was causing the error?

Comment: [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is module in the standard library.  Your file shadowed the standard library version, because the working directory is included in the search path of the `import` statement.  Anything that tried to use the standard library would find your file instead.

Comment: Oh my bad! thank you for helping me out :)